# What does ethernet switch do with IP address

Tags: switch, router, dhcp, switching

Sorry about asking stupid question here but I'm very new to this field...
Here is my current set up:

```
                _____ NAS
                |
Modem --- Router ---  Server
                |____ Desktop
```

I have Nas, a server desktop and my personal desktop connected to my router with ethernet cable. They all have 10.0.1.x IP ranges and they can talk to each other appearently. The router also supports Wifi connection and I can see my NAS through wireless devices.

Now I want to add two more ethernet connection to my router but I do not have ethernet port anymore. I did lots of research online and they are all talking about switch. My question is, will I still have the 10.0.1.x IP range if I use a switch?

If I use the below set up, can I access NAS from all my desktops? Will my server and desktops see each other within the same network(The network folder in My Computer from windows 10 for example)

```
                _____ NAS
                |
Modem --- Router ---  Server
                |            _____  Desktop 1
                |            |
                |____ Switch -----  Desktop 2
                             |____  Desktop 3
```

I am using an Airport Extreme and it only provides three ethernet ports. All I actually need is few more ports...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, switches essentially expand the amount of devices you can potentially connect. An un-managed switch will be able to accomplish this task for your situation. The desktops and any other devices you may connect to the switch will behave as if they were connected directly to the router.

Keep in mind that all devices connected to said switch will have to share the bandwidth of the single link to your router.

Comment: Ok Thanks! That being said, my NAS will affect the network speed of all my desktop, right? So from what you said about the expanding port thing, I can move my NAS below the switch and still access it from Wifi or desktops, right(More demend on desktops)?

Comment: The only way your NAS would affect your desktop speeds is if it was connected to the switch, and was sending large amounts of data to a device that is not directly connected to the switch.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You will be able to access your NAS from all the desktops. The switch works in L2 layer.

Your DHCP discovery request will reach the Router and  all the Desktops will get the IP from the LAN subnet configured in the router abd you will get IP from 10.0.1.x range itself